# Using processing.runalg in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I try to create a common extent for rasters in QGIS 2.99. Here is my script:

```
import processing

processing.runalg("script:unifyextentandresolution",
                  "/qgis_data/rasters/Image2.tif;
                  /qgis_data/rasters/Image1.tif",
                 -9999,"/qgis_data/rasters",True)
```

However, `processing.runalg` is being used for QGIS 2.99. I need it for QGIS 2.99

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use:

```
processing.run()
```

which is the equivalent to the QGIS <= 2.18 version:

```
processing.runalg()
```

---

I'm not sure how you created your input parameters in your script but I used the following dictionary format for a simple script (change the `PARAMETER_X` names with the ones you used:

```
import processing
parameters = {'PARAMETER_1': "/qgis_data/rasters/Image2.tif; /qgis_data/rasters/Image1.tif",
                'PARAMETER_2': -9999,
                'PARAMETER_3': "/qgis_data/rasters",
                'PARAMETER_4': True}

processing.run('script:unifyextentandresolution', parameters)
```

Comment: I also know that 'alghelp' processing method changed to 'algorithmHelp' but, do you know what is equivalent method to 'alglist'? I tried it out some posible candidates but it didn't work (they are not callable). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @xunilk - That's a good question and worth being asked as a [new one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). I checked some of the source files but couldn't find a dedicated method like `alglist`. Instead, you could use `dir(processing.algs.qgis)` or `dir(processing.algs.gdal)` to get their respective algorithms but also various other methods. You could get a list of algorithms from the processing help description as described in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252148/processing-in-qgis-2-99) but can't confirm if all algorithms listed are present.

Comment: Joseph, thanks a lot but as a new question would be marked as duplicated because answer I'm looking for is in your link post (+1 for you there).

Comment: I posted an answer in your link post for complementing yours because `dir(processing.algs.qgis)` and `dir(processing.algs.gdal)` have some issues (all methods names are listed with some uppercase letters and they need to be expressed with all letters lowercase).

Comment: @xunilk - I noticed your answer (already upvoted it) and glad you posted a nice method to getting all algorithms, not necessarily just for `qgis` ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'll update for saga too. By the way, you are right when you say  that you can't confirm if all algorithms listed are present. I know that 'saga:rastercalculator' is present and it's not listed yet.

Comment: @Joseph I have written this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294996/error-in-executing-voronoi-polygon-algorithm   still i am not getting any output