# Running algorithms in PyQGIS (QGIS 3)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'd like to use PyQGIS to run algorithms from the toolbox in QGIS 2.99 but *runalg* does not seem to be known.

For instance, the following would generate a grid in QGIS 2.18:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:creategrid', 1, '467009.285713,480668.436073,5610112.91342,5615790.0642', 500, 500, r'EPSG:25832',r'D:\tobedeleted\trash\grid.shp')
```

But now it gives me:

```
AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'runalg'
```

I checked the QGIS 3 [API breaks for processing](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_Processing) and although methods like *alglist* were removed it does not mention runalg.

Comment: You mean like here [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261926/processing-runalg-usage-in-qgis-2-99](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261926/processing-runalg-usage-in-qgis-2-99)?

Comment: No clue how I did not find this... I searched for a while... this question can be closed and marked as a duplicate.