# Creating raster layer from line with PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-3

I try to create a raster layer from a line shape on canvas.

This raster layer band values should be equal and different from other cells. For instance the cells which consists line should be 0 other sides should be 1 - of course other side values should be equal, as well.

There is a tool which helps me about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to processing and gdal.

**Using QGIS 2.18**

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/fr/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html

There is for your purpose one algorithm that fits well : *gdal rasterize*. You can use it as follow:

```
import processing

processing.runalg("gdalogr:rasterize","path/to/your/vector/layer.shp","area",1,100,100,"869423.623626,934698.45436,6310430.7313,6345492.27874",False,5,"",4,75,6,1,False,0,"",None)
```

for the many option see `processing.alghelp("gdalogr:rasterize")` in your console.

**Using QGIS 3.0**

Same principle with `processing.run`... You may want to have a look here : [Using processing.runalg in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261926/using-processing-runalg-in-qgis-3/262059)