# Calling a QgsProcessingAlgorithm from a Processing python script in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, algorithm, qgis-3

I am writing a `Processing` python script based on the template provided [here](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).

I am creating lines (destined to the 'OUTPUT') and I would like to clip them according to a polygon entered as the 'INPUT' parameter).
I can't figure out how to call the Algorithm. For what it's worth, this doesn't work:
`QgsProcessingAlgorithm('qgis:clip').run({'INPUT': self.OUTPUT, 'OVERLAY': self.INPUT})`

I have tried several ways but couldn't get far as I get the error:
`qgis._core.QgsProcessingAlgorithm represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated`

Comment: 'Abstract class' means you cannot instantiate it like `QgsProcessingAlgorithm(..)` or `variable = QgsProcessingAlgorithm()`. Other classes inherit from it just like `class NewProcessingAlg(QgsProcessingAlgorithm)`

Comment: `processing.run()` See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262059/2856 and to get the input parameter syntax easily, run the alg manually and have a look at the processing history.

Comment: @Luke ok, processing.run() seems the way to go (it felt counter-intuitive as we have QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingAlgRunner and many other classes). Now, any idea as to how I pipe this to my algorithm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following to work:

```
temp = QgsVectorLayer('Line', 'temp', 'memory')
# do some stuff with temp
clipped_lines = processing.run('native:clip', {
        'INPUT': temp,
        'OVERLAY': parameters['INPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:ClippedLines',
    }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can execute 'qgis:clip' in python as follows.

```
alg='qgis:clip'
params = {"INPUT": inputLayer,"OVERLAY": clipLayer,"OUTPUT":clippedLayer}
processing.run(alg, params)
```

Comment: I had figured that part from a previous suggestion, now what I am trying to do is have `qgis:clip` take the current output of my algorithm as input and then let the final output be my algorithm output. Not sure this is clear but basically I want to call this inside my algorithm and let it return the final output... still stuck here.

Comment: please share the code snippet of your algorithm I may be able to help you in matter.

Comment: It's based on [this template](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/), I have just changed the logic to actually do something but I'm using the `QgsProcessingFeatureSink` just as in the template.

Comment: You can try something like this  
`clip_area = processing.runalg("qgis:clip", input_layer, clip_layer,clipped_layer)  
fin_area = processing.runalg("qgis:dissolve", clip_area['OUTPUT'], 
"true", None, processed_layer)`