# Clipping vector by iterating through input clippers using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, clip, qgis-processing

I have a python script that I want to work in QGIS 3.0.

```
#importing all necessary modules
import processing, os, glob

result_path =("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/Regions_Min/Province/TI/CADT/") #specifying the result path/directory
os.chdir("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/Mindanao_provinces/") #changing the directory where the input files are located
clipper_path ="/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/Mindanao_provinces/"

for fname in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    name = list(os.path.splitext(fname)) #convert an iterable to list
    name[0] = name[0] + ""
    newName = "".join(name)
    print ("processing " + newName)
    overlay = newName.replace(".shp", "_clipped.shp") #indicating the ouput shapefile by replacing some of its letter strings
    input_vector = ("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/Regions_Min/TI/CADT.shp") #specify the input vector to be clipped
    #processing.runalg("qgis:clip", input_vector, fname, result_path + overlay) #run the clip algorithm
    alg ="qgis:clip"
    params = {"INPUT": input_vector,"OVERLAY": clipper_path+fname,"OUTPUT":result_path + overlay}
    processing.run(alg, params)
print("Finish")
```

Please take note that the commented line (#processing.runalg("qgis:clip...)
worked in 2.18. I tried to follow the new convention of QGIS 3 processing in this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278834/calling-a-qgsprocessingalgorithm-from-a-processing-python-script-in-qgis-3-0).

This is the resulting error from the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 105, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 183, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

Is there something I missed with my python script?

Comment: Could you upgrade your QGIS version? This works for me using 3.6.2 for Windows.

Comment: Hello, I'll try upgrading my QGIS, but I have plans for sticking with the QGIS LTR (Madeira) version in the long run.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.6, but I still encounter the same error.