# Creating a roughness ASCII file from a raster dataset

Tags: qgis, python, raster, qgis-python-console

I'm trying to create a roughness file (derived from topography) in the ASCII format for a European raster dataset. This dataset is from the EEA.

I've already made an ASCII grid file of the raster data as a whole (euroascii.asc) using the command:

`gdal_translate -of AAIGrid ~/elevation3x3/elevation3x3.tif euroascii.asc`

The roughness file has to be continuous (AKA 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, and so on), and has to account for every value that is already in the `euroascii.asc` file.

There is a command that is meant to do just this (I think), but I've tried it in the QGIS Python Console and it doesn't work.

This is what I've done in the QGIS Python Console, taken direct from the manual:

`import processing` # this gets no errors or anything out

And also:

```
from qgis import processing
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
        print(alg.id(), "->", alg.displayName()
```

To test whether this has any effect, I tried the code from https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/roughness.html

`processing.runalg('gdalogr:roughness', EEAdata, 1, compute_edges=F, roughnessFile)`

Which gets the error:

`AttributeError: module 'qgis.processing' has no attribute 'runalg'`

I'm only using QGIS Hannover, with no access to ArcGIS or any other commercial software. I'm also running this on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This thread answers your question [Using processing.runalg in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261926/using-processing-runalg-in-qgis-3)

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz thank you!