# Rasterize in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How can I apply rasterizing process in QGIS 3.0. I know it is very simple quesiton. However I cannot find the rasterize tool.

**EDIT**

I rasterized a layer with GDAL\rasterize tool by using script which is:

```
parameters={"INPUT": layer,
                           "FIELD": "PolygonId",
                           "DIMENSIONS": 0,
                           "WIDTH": rps,
                           "HEIGHT": rps,
                           "RAST_EXT": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                           "TFW": 1,
                           "RTYPE": 6,
                           "NO_DATA": 0,
                           "COMPRESS": 0,
                           "JPEGCOMPRESSION": 1,
                           "ZLEVEL": 1,
                           "PREDICTOR": 1,
                           "TILED": False,
                           "BIGTIFF": 2,
                           "EXTRA": '',
                           "OUTPUT": dosya}
processing.runAndLoadResults("gdal:rasterize",parameters)
```

However it does not work now.
I found the rasterize.py under this:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\plugins\processing\algs\gdal\rasterize.py
```

I cannot use it again. What is the solution for rasterize by using at least these parameters;

```
Input, Field, Width, Height, Rasterize extension, Output
```

Comment: Remember that 2.99 is still a dev version and that there was a big UI change and some tools may still need to be ported over.  Under Processing > Toolbox, there is 'Convert Map to Raster' and GRASS' `v.to.rast.value`.  Additionally, gdal is a standalone toolset which you can find on disk.

Comment: Yes you are right but it does not help me. I should edit my question.

Comment: @Mustafa Uçar In my af5b2a750 QGIS 2.99 release, gdal:rasterize tool has not been ported  yet.

Comment: @xunilk is there any places where I can follow wheather it is ported

Comment: Simplest method is opening both QGIS installed versions. In each Processing Tool Box browse by gdal. In QGIS 2.99 you will be able to observe that gdal:rasterize doesn't exist. Another way is by using methods in this link: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252148/processing-in-qgis-2-99/263171#263171