# processing.runalg() throws "TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed"

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

Hi everyone I'm in some way new with PyQGIS and I've been trying to run a script in QGIS 3.0 without success (it prefectly ran in 2.18) and always get the same error:

*AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'runalg'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "", line 8, in 
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed*

Does this has something to do with PYTHONPATH? I can't even see the list of algorithms when typing: processing.alglist()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not an answer to the original question, but to a follow-up question in a comment ("Also how can I see the list and options of algorithms?").

In QGIS 3, the processing algorithms can be listed in the QGIS Python console (Python 3) using (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274902/22646 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274874/22646):

```
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms()
```

To list the names (IDs):

```
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms(): print(alg.id())
```

Getting help for an algorithm (including input parameters and output):

```
processing.algorithmHelp("qgis:union")
```

There is also:

```
processing.algs.help.shortHelp.keys()
print("\n".join(processing.algs.help.shortHelp.keys()))
```

But it does not seem to include algorithms from for instance gdal and grass.

Comment: The QGIS documentation has now been updated (see http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html).

Comment: Great answer, @Håvard Tveite . I am having trouble running an external PyQGIS script though, since it cannot find the processing algorithm I'm trying to run:
processing.run("qgis:rastersampling", params)

I can run any ("native") processing algorithm easily by adding QgsNativeAlgorithms() via the following line: 
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

But I'm not sure how to add a similar line to add any of the "qgis" processing algorithms. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

In QGIS 3, use `processing.run`.

For instance:

QGIS 2.x `processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat', ...`

QGIS 3.0 `processing.run('gdal:convertformat', ...`

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Also how can I see the list and options of algorithms? I've tried processing.alglist() and processing.list() but both throw a similar error.