# How can I get information displayed at tooltips for each algorithm's name at Processing Toolbox for QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I use following code for searching adequate id name for each algorithm presents in Processing Toolbox (gdal, grass7, qgis, saga) for QGIS 3.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

gdal_path_algs = processing.algs.gdal.__path__[0]
grass_path_algs = processing.algs.grass7.__path__[0] + '/description'
qgis_path_algs = processing.algs.qgis.__path__[0]
saga_path_algs = processing.algs.saga.__path__[0] + '/description'

gdal_algs = [ 'gdal:' + file[:-3].lower() for file in listdir(gdal_path_algs) if isfile(join(gdal_path_algs, file)) ]
grass_algs = [ 'grass7:' + file[:-4].lower() for file in listdir(grass_path_algs) if isfile(join(grass_path_algs, file)) ]
qgis_algs = [ 'qgis:' + file[:-3].lower() for file in listdir(qgis_path_algs) if isfile(join(qgis_path_algs, file)) ]
saga_algs = [ 'saga:' + file[:-4].lower() for file in listdir(saga_path_algs) if isfile(join(saga_path_algs, file)) ]

#print (gdal_algs)
#print (grass_algs)
#print (qgis_algs)
print (saga_algs)
```

However, when list algorithms is printed at Python Console, for instance **saga**, some of them has special characters ("-", "(", ")") or author's name of algorithm and **id's name** doesn't work for retrieving parameters list by using 'algorithmHelp' processing method.

Afterwards, I founded out that tooltips displayed when I put cursor over algorithm's name at Processing Toolbox (see following image) had correct information I need. How can I get information displayed at tooltips for each algorithm's name at Processing Toolbox for QGIS 3 as alternative approach of my above code?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it might be better to obtain the algorithms' details directly from the [QgsApplication::processingRegistry()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsApplication.html#a299fa409526818bb9810963fa240e22e), you could then store the display names and algorithm ID in a dictionary (or list). Then you can call the ID by entering the name displayed in the *Processing Toolbox* or from the tooltip:

```
gdal_algs = {}
grass_algs = {}
qgis_algs = {}
saga_algs = {}

for algs in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
    if 'gdal' in algs.id():
        gdal_algs[algs.displayName()] = 'Algorithm ID: ' + algs.id()
    if 'grass7' in algs.id():
        grass_algs[algs.displayName()] = 'Algorithm ID: ' + algs.id()
    if 'qgis' in algs.id():
        qgis_algs[algs.displayName()] = 'Algorithm ID: ' + algs.id()
    if 'saga' in algs.id():
        saga_algs[algs.displayName()] = 'Algorithm ID: ' + algs.id()
```

Then use the following to get the ID of your chosen algorithm:

```
saga_algs['Imcorr - feature tracking']

>>>'Algorithm ID: saga:imcorrfeaturetracking'
```

I'm not sure how to access the tooltip directly to get the same info.

---

**EDIT:**

You could also just bundle all algorithms into a single dictionary and call the `algorithmHelp()` function for the tool you're interested in:

```
algorithms = {}
for algs in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
        algorithms[algs.displayName()] = algs.id()

processing.algorithmHelp(algorithms['Imcorr - feature tracking'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph. This is the answer that I wanted. This is information displayed at each tooltip.

Comment: @xunilk - Most welcome, glad it helped! Edited post to include another method to directly get the help parameters by creating a single dictionary instead :)

Comment: Thanks again @Joseph. For my plugin I think is enough with this list form: `algs = [ alg.id() for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms() ]`. I'll see it later.