# Where to find documentation on algorithm parameters when writing scripts in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

For older versions of QGIS, the algorithm parameters were documented in the 'Console usage' section in the QGIS documentation (e.g. the [reproject layer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools.html#reproject-layer) documentation). In the QGIS 3 documentation (e.g. [reproject layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer) documentation) there is no 'Console usage' section. Where can I find out how to use the algorithms in my scripts, especially since many of them have changed?

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** See also the answer to [QGIS 3.0 Error when calling processing.runalg()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276647/8503) which is also a complete answer to this question.

I found that the easiest way to get documentation on the algorithms is to use `processing.algorithmHelp` from the QGIS Python Console (enable with Plugins > Python Console). For example, typing `processing.algorithmHelp("native:reprojectlayer")` into the interactive console gives this documentation:

```
Reproject layer (native:reprojectlayer)

This algorithm reprojects a vector layer. It creates a new layer with the same features as the input one, but with geometries reprojected to a new CRS.

Attributes are not modified by this algorithm.


----------------
Input parameters
----------------

INPUT: Input layer

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource

    Accepted data types:
        - str: layer ID
        - str: layer name
        - str: layer source
        - QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition
        - QgsProperty
        - QgsVectorLayer

TARGET_CRS: Target CRS

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterCrs

    Accepted data types:
        - str: 'ProjectCrs'
        - str: CRS auth ID (e.g. 'EPSG:3111')
        - str: CRS PROJ4 (e.g. 'PROJ4:...')
        - str: CRS WKT (e.g. 'WKT:...')
        - str: layer ID. CRS of layer is used.
        - str: layer name. CRS of layer is used.
        - str: layer source. CRS of layer is used.
        - QgsMapLayer: CRS of layer is used
        - QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition: CRS of source is used
        - QgsProperty

OUTPUT: Reprojected

    Parameter type: QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink

    Accepted data types:
        - str: destination vector file, e.g. 'd:/test.shp'
        - str: 'memory:' to store result in temporary memory layer
        - str: using vector provider ID prefix and destination URI, e.g. 'postgres:...' to store result in PostGIS table
        - QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition
        - QgsProperty

----------------
Outputs
----------------

OUTPUT:  <QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer>
    Reprojected
```

To figure out what the algorithm identifier is (e.g. `native:reprojectlayer`) you can run the algorithm from the toolbox, and then check in the history to see the name (and you what parameters were passed).

[image: Checking the algorithm history]

Another way to get the algorithm identifier is to hover your mouse over one of the algorithms in the toolbox.

[image]