# Finding source code of "fill sinks (wang and liu)"

Tags: qgis, saga

I would like to use the source code of "fill sinks (wang and liu)".

I checked through QGIS3 folders, but could not find much related to it.

Anyone know where the code could be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fill Sinks (Wang and Liu) is a QGIS  processing algorithm that calls an external (3rd party) tool SAGA.

The code to call SAGA is in [SagaAlgorithm.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithm.py).

The source for the SAGA command is either:

- [FillSinks_WL.cpp](https://github.com/saga-gis/saga-gis/blob/master/saga-gis/src/tools/terrain_analysis/ta_preprocessor/FillSinks_WL.cpp) or
- [FillSinks_WL_XXL.cpp](https://github.com/saga-gis/saga-gis/blob/master/saga-gis/src/tools/terrain_analysis/ta_preprocessor/FillSinks_WL_XXL.cpp)

Comment: How would I go about calling the SAGA command using SagaAlgorithm.py through an IDE?

Comment: @Suspectful, [`processing.run`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274778). If you have further questions,ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

The Wang and Liu algorithm is also implemented in [Whitebox GIS](https://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml). You can find it listed under Hydrological Tools\DEM Pre-processing\Fill Depressions.

The source code can be very easily accessed using Whitebox's 'View Code' button on the tool. You can also navigate to the text file yourself.  Or you can view it [online](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/blob/master/resources/plugins/Scripts/FillDepressions.groovy). The code is written in [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/), a java-based scripting language.

Comment: And *this* is one of the things I love about WB GIS. It took me a lot of mucking around to figure out where the source for the QGIS/SAGA implementation was...  With WB GIS you can access it from the program itself.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Groovy-based implementation that Chris mentioned (a Whitebox GAT plugin), there is also a newer and more efficient [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/)-based open-source implementation of the Wang and Lui depression filling method available in [`WhiteboxTools`](https://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/index.html). The source code for this tool can be found in the `WhiteboxTools` [Github repository](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/blob/master/src/tools/hydro_analysis/fill_depressions.rs). Importantly, `WhiteboxTools` can be run independent of `Whitebox GAT` (i.e. the Whitebox GIS user interface) and can be scripted using Python (See [here](https://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/WhiteboxTools/interacting_through_python.html) for details).

```py
from WBT.whitebox_tools import WhiteboxTools
wbt = WhiteboxTools()

dem = "/path/to/data/DEM.tif"
output = "/path/to/data/filled_DEM.tif"
wbt.fill_depressions(dem, output)
```

Additionally, this Rust-based depression filling tool is available from the [Whitebox for Processing](https://plugins.bruy.me/processing-whitebox.html) QGIS plugin:

[image]