# PyQGIS 3.4: otb:unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification -> AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'runalg'

Tags: raster, classification, pyqgis-3, otb-applications

I'm trying to classify a raster with PyQGIS:

`import processing
processing.runalg("otb:unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification","FalseColor.tif",128,None,100,3,1000,0.95,"class.tif",None)`
The python console indicate :

> AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'runalg'

It is a little bit surprising because I've followed the QGIS documentation. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/learning.html#unsupervised-kmeans-image-classification

I've seen this post: [QGIS 3.0 Error when calling processing.runalg()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274764/qgis-3-0-error-when-calling-processing-runalg)

I've tried with `processing.run`:
`processing.run("otb:unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification","FalseColor.tif",128,None,100,3,1000,0.95,"class.tif",None)`

The python console indicate :

> TypeError: run() takes from 2 to 5 positional arguments but 10 were given

Is there an updated documentation about the algorithm `otb:unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification`?

Comment: have you found a solution yet? Would be interested in an answer as well

Comment: No, I haven't found anything interesting. The QGIS documentation is not finished. I hope I will find something later.

Comment: meanwhile I had success with processing.runAlgorithm instead of processing.runalg

Comment: @geekornolife Hi there, could you share how you managed to call from processing and QGIS 3.4 please? I have been lost ...